# Create If statement based if cell above is occupied

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell, isnull

I would like to write an `IF` statement in Excel that is based on the cell above being occupied.

The `IF` statement should be: if any cell below the "name" cell is occupied, it should be colored red. Just like in the image below.

[image]

Comment: look into conditional formatting, where you can create a rule that refers to the cell above.

Answer (score 0):

follow the below steps:

- Conditional Formatting
- New Rule
- use a formula to determine which cells to format
- copy this formula =IF(ISBLANK(B4),FALSE,TRUE)
- apply to your range

Comment: the `IF` wrapper is not needed.  Only `=B4<>""` will do it.  ISBLANK may return false negatives if the values are filled with formula that have a `""` return option.